# FTP suddenly stopped listing files in a particular directory

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I have a server on an inmotion hosting account that is suddenly acting strangely for FTP, but only in a particular directory. It is simply refusing to list the files. I've tried with two clients - FileZilla (which was working up until yesterday), and WinSCP. I checked the firewall rules to ensure that passive FTP was enabled, but they were. I then logged into cPanel to check that the files were still there, and they were. The support agent I talked to was able to list the files in his FileZilla client, so the problem must be on my side. What direction do I start looking for answers at this point?

EDIT: I tested this on another computer on my network that had never had FileZilla installed before, and it produced the same problem.

EDIT: The directory in question appears to have inexplicably changed to the "nobody" group. The owner is still correct (the same user I'm using to FTP in is the owner), but the group is now different. I have shell access, and attempted to change the group. Even though in the shell it shows that the directory's group has been changed, that change does not seem to propagate to FTP.

Comment: What are the rights on the directory which does not work, and on the directory which does work. Has the one which does not work no `x` bit set?

Comment: Any error message? Or does it just show empty folder? Have you looked in the client log file? Anything striking there?

Comment: No error message. The permissions on all the folders seem to be 755, including the non-working one. If I create a new folder in that folder with FileZilla, I can see it with FileZilla, but none of the existing folders. The client logs claim 4 matches for the directory listing, but it neither shows 4 entries, nor actually has 4 files/subdirectories. I find that particularly odd.

Comment: Did you restart or SIGHUP the ftpd after changing the group?

Comment: Restarting the service didn't seem to help. It's pure-ftpd, if that makes a difference.